# Problemas com função em PHP - PDO

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\trofeugs2017\model\Model.php on line 81
```

Como corrigir o erro?

Código:

```
<?php
class Model {

 protected $name_table;
 protected $fields;
 protected $id_row;
 public $con;


 public function __construct($name_table){
  $this->name_table = $name_table;
  $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=trofeu2017", "root", ""); 
 }      
 function implodeFields($fields){
  return implode(', ', $fields);
 }
 function implodeKeys($fields){
  return implode(', ', array_keys($fields));
 }
 function implodeValues($fields){
  return "'" . implode("', '", array_values($fields)) . "'";
 }      
 public function updateTable(array $fields, $where){         
  if($where){
   $where = "WHERE {$where}";
  } else {
   $where = null;
  }
  foreach($fields as $key => $values){
   $campos[] = "`{$key}` = '{$values}'";
  }
  $fields = $this->implodeFields($campos);
  $sql = "UPDATE {$this->name_table} SET {$fields} {$where}";
  $update = $this->con->prepare($sql);
  if($update->execute()){
   return $update;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Seu erro está dando na linha 81, mas seu código só possui 41 linhas. Esse é todo o código que há no arquivo `Model.php`?

Comment: O erro indica que a conexão está vazia ou pegou a variável errada.

Comment: Pessoal obrigado pela resposta, mas acabei descobrindo o erro, mas respondendo vcs, as linhas q omiti era de insert e select, e o erro seria na linha " $update = $this->con->prepare($sql);".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente, você esta passando uma variável vazia ou errado no comando `prepare`

Use o comando localizar do seu IDE e procure por `prepare` e verifique as variáveis passadas.

Comment: Obrigado Lucas, mas já descobri o erro!